# How to compare twon nested json in python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have output Json

```
{
  "id": "641f295a-9db7-4013-a909-3fede326897d", 
  "result": {
    "action": "order_status", 
    "actionIncomplete": false, 
    "contexts": [], 
    "fulfillment": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "lang": "en", 
          "speech": "Please choose any of the following options: \n<ul class=\"botResponse\">\n<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=bot.sendEvent('Order_Details')> Order Status basis Order Number </a></li>\n<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=bot.sendEvent('Customer_Name')> Order Status basis Customer Name </a></li>\n</ul>", 
          "type": 0
        }
      ], 
      "speech": "Please choose any of the following options: \n<ul class=\"botResponse\">\n<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=bot.sendEvent('Order_Details')> Order Status basis Order Number </a></li>\n<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=bot.sendEvent('Customer_Name')> Order Status basis Customer Name </a></li>\n</ul>"
    }, 
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "641f295a-9db7-4013-a909-3fede326897d", 
      "intentList": [
        "Order_Status"
      ], 
      "intentName": "Order_Status", 
      "webhookUsed": "false"
    }, 
    "parameters": {}, 
    "resolvedQuery": "status for all orders", 
    "score": 0.7271162920052577, 
    "source": "agent"
  }, 
  "sessionId": "12345", 
  "status": {
    "code": 200, 
    "errorType": "success"
  }, 
  "timestamp": "2019-07-26T18:05:44.357705"
}
```

and  need to compare same with same type of input json which having nested dic list object.
on columns : 
sessionId

status.code status.errorType

result.metadata.intentName

action  actionIncomplete

result.fulfillment.messages

result.fulfillment.speech

result.metadata.intentId

result.metadata.intentList

parameters

result.contexts

I have done string comparison but due to some extra character its giving error

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more info

Comment: i have two JSON, one with expected output and one which i get via api calls and i have to compare this two JSON and find the count of fail test on above mention columns and can ignore other columns. there are 12 columns to compare. mention aboved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
    def compare_1(self, source_data_a, source_data_b):
        def compare(data_a, data_b):
            if type(data_a) is list:
                if (type(data_b) != list) or (len(data_a) != len(data_b)):
                    return False
                for list_index, list_item in enumerate(data_a):
                    if not compare(list_item, data_b[list_index]):
                        return False
                return True
            if type(data_a) is dict:
                if type(data_b) != dict:
                    return False
                for dict_key, dict_value in data_a.items():
                    if (dict_key not in data_b) or (not compare(dict_value, data_b[dict_key])):
                        return False
                return True
            if (type(data_a) is str) and (type(data_b) is str):
                one, two = self.string(data_a, data_b)
                if one == two:
                    return True

            if (type(data_a) is int) or (type(data_a) is numpy.int64) or (type(data_a) is numpy.int32):
                if type(data_b) != int:
                    data_b = int(data_b)
                    return compare(data_a, data_b)
                else:
                    return data_a == data_b
            if (type(data_a) is numpy.bool_ or bool) and (type(data_b) is numpy.bool_ or bool):
                return data_a == data_b
            return (data_a == data_b) and (type(data_a) is type(data_b))

        return compare(source_data_a, source_data_b) and compare(source_data_b, source_data_a)```
````